# UIbutton in UITableViewCell in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uitableview

I'm new to objective-C and strucked at a point ..I'm adding a `UILabel(Name)`,`UIbutton(Cancel)` in `UITableViewCell` and when I click on it  `UIButton` it shows an alertView with two button Yes and No .When I go for Yes I have to get the corresponding `UIlabel(Name)` value of that cell.But I could not understand how to do it ?
This is the code  Im writing for creating a `UILabel` and `UIButton`..

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *d = (NSMutableDictionary *) [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 UILabel *name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45, 320,15)];
    name .font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];        
    [name setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [name  setText:[d valueForKey:@"Name"]];
    name.tag=112;
    [cell addSubview:name];
    [name  release];    

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(100.0f, 50.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f);
    [btn setTitle:@"Delete Details" forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
    [cell addSubview:btn];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:)
                             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;     
}
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender

{



    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure" message:@"You want to delete Details" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
                          [alert show];
                          [alert release];    

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex   
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) 
    {
       [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; 

     }
    else 
    {
        //I have to get the corresponding cells UILabel value. 
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons which you are creating should some how have a variable which points to which cell they are in.

```
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(100.0f, 50.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f);
    [btn setTitle:@"Delete Details" forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
    [cell addSubview:btn];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:)
                         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

should be

```
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    // The below line will add a state to each button which you can use to later differentiate in your method: btnClicked
    [btn setTag:indexPath.row]; 
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(100.0f, 50.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f);
    [btn setTitle:@"Delete Details" forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
    [cell addSubview:btn];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:)
                         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



   you can set some variable which is global to the class like "selectedRow". You can declare it on the top of the class after the line @implementation. Look for a line called

   @implementation yourClassName

   //Add the below declaration. This is a global variable in your class, which you can set in one method and access in other methods
   int selectedRow;
```

and in btnClicked

```
//Add the below line
selectedRow=[sender tag];
```

and in the final method of alertView clickedAlert at

```
   // NSLog(@"Name selected is ",[arr objectAtIndex:selectedRow] objectForKey:@"Name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a variable in your class that is readable from anywhere. It could be a `NSString` or even an `NSDictionary` with more information. Set it when you create the alert. Destroy it (set it to `nil`) when you exit the alert.

To get to the info in your button routine:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
UIView *cellContentView = button.superview.superview;
UILabel *label = (UILabel*) [cellContentView viewWithTag:yourPredefinedTag];
_privateVariable = label.text;
```

Comment: I couldnot get u .What I need is when I click on UIButton of a cell I will be presented with an alertView .When I click on Yes then I should get that particular cells  label value where I click on the UIbutton of that cell..How can I do it ?

Comment: When the button is clicked you can get to the cell like in my edit I will add to the answer.

Comment: But I have to add it in UIAlertView as I have mentioned in my code.Then it is not allowing this stmnt" UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;"

Comment: Wrong. You create the alert view in your button handler.

Comment: Thats what I was doing .Im creating it here - (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender{UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure" message:@"You want to delete Details" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
                          [alert show];
                          [alert release]; }

Comment: -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex   
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) 
    {
       [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; 

     }
    else 
    {
        //I have to get the corresponding cells UILabel value. 
     }

Comment: So? Just before creating it, set the string variable as shown.

Comment: I have to get that particular cells Name.But Im geting the same Name when I click a UIbutton of any cell...How can I do it ?

Comment: That depends where you are storing this data. Look, it seems that you should take a CS class or really try to understand some basic tutorials rather than using your valuable time so inefficiently.